# Drupal homepage customization

Tags: 7, nodes

i want to add some feature in drupal home page, like:
1) All new posts will be arranged greed
2) A thumbnail will appear from post photos
3) Text of content will be minimized to 150 words
so, how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: i am using drupal 7

Comment: Have a look at Views & Panels module.

Answer (score 0):

What @Kantu already said. Take a look at this tutorial: [Panels 3: Creating a new front page with Views and Panels 3](http://drupal.org/node/206792).